# How to distinguish firstst rows in SQLite statement

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I have table like this:

```
_id| letter| extra
1  | A     | some
2  | A     | another
3  | A     | information
4  | B     | NULL
5  | B     | 98090
```

I need to distinguish first rows when LETTER changes:

```
_id| letter| extra       | mediator
1  | A     | some        | 1
2  | A     | another     | 
3  | A     | information |
4  | B     | NULL        | 1
5  | B     | 98090       |
```

Or ...

```
_id| letter| extra       | count
1  | A     | some        | 1
2  | A     | another     | 2
3  | A     | information | 3
4  | B     | NULL        | 1
5  | B     | 98090       | 2
```

(in this case, I know that I need count = 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query searches for those IDs (assuming that "first" means "smallest `_id` value"):

```
SELECT MIN(_id)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY letter
```

The followin statement will set the `mediator` column:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET mediator = 1
WHERE _id IN (SELECT MIN(_id)
              FROM MyTable
              GROUP BY letter)
```